# Direct upload to s3 without the use of a production server

Tags: php, asp.net, drupal, upload, amazon-s3

We are creating a media driven website that requires our users to submit very large broadcast quality video files over the internet.  We want to cut bandwidth issues out by eliminating the use of our production server (where the website is), and just creating a connection between the user and a s3 account.

To make matters even more fun, our hosting service only allows 50MB an upload through PHP...

I've looked all over the internet for a feasible solution, can anybody help?

A progress bar would be terrific as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with the [S3 POST upload API.](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) If you need a progress bar, [you can do that easily on HTML5 browsers](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/); if you need to support older browsers you may need a flash uploader.

Comment: I guess I should add that it isn't going to amazon, the media is going to archive.org

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to somehow provide your S3 credentials to your users, then, which I doubt you'd want to do.
It'd be the only way to have the users direct upload to S3 without involving your server.

Comment: Except, S3 has an API specifically for this, which does not expose your S3 credentials.