# How to create folder under Amazon S3 bucket through PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am developing an iPhone app to allow user upload photo and share. I want to use S3 to store uploaded images as well as processed images (foe example, thumbnail, reduced size image). I've installed AWS PHP SDK on my EC2 instance.

My questions are:

1. Should photos uploaded from iPhone app go to a EC2 directory first, then copied over to S3 bucket, or it should directly uploaded to S3?
2. How can I create different folders under the S3 bucket through PHP SDK and how to read the files from the folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The answer can be found here:
   [Direct upload to s3 without the use of a production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712733/direct-upload-to-s3-without-the-use-of-a-production-server)
2. I've never used the PHP SDK, but I was browsing through the [AWS SDK
   for PHP 1.5.14
   documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/)
   and came across the following APIs that you will need to utilize:

   a) [create_object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/create_object) : You'll use this to put a object into a bucket.  You'll specify the filename.  You asked how you can create different folders: you will include the full path into the filename.  For instance instead of naming the file "photo1.jpg", you would name it "user1/vacation/photo1.jpg".

   b) [get_object_list](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_list) : This API will return to you a list of objects given some criteria.  If you want to read all the objects from a particular folder, specify the prefix as the path to the folder.  For instance, if I want to find all files in the folder "user1/vacation/", I would specify my prefix to be "user1/vacation/".

Answer (score 35):

**Yes** , it is possible to create new folder using `s3` sdk.

try bellow code

```
<?php

 /* abc is the folder name */

 $s3->putObject(array( 
                   'Bucket' => $bucket,
                   'Key'    => "abc/",
                   'Body'   => "",
                   'ACL'    => 'public-read'
                  ));
```